# check pervious value in iteration in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have the below code which is getting some data from the database.

```
  $assigneesbyrfc= Assignee::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])
    ->wherenotnull('rfc_id')
    ->orderBy('rfc_id','desc')
    ->get();
```

and sending it as collection, when sending it to my view, I need to check the current value with the previous one. if there is a match a note should appear.

```
                @foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
                <tr>
                @if(!$loop->first && $assignee->rfc_id == $assignee[$loop->index - 1]->rfc_id)
                <td>{{$assignee->rfc_id}} it matches!!</td>
                @else
                <td>Nope</td>
   @endif
```

I keep getting error when I am trying to have it in an if statement

I am getting below error;

```
  1   ErrorException::("Trying to get property 'rfc_id' of non-object")
```

Comment: $assignee is object? or array? The error code shows it's non-object.

Comment: @TomaszBucko its a collection. I am using get(); to fetch it from the database.

Comment: Don't you mean `...== $assignees[$loop->index - 1]->rfc_id)` ? Note the last `s` at `assignees`. `assignees` is a collection array, `assignee` an object in the collection.

Comment: @Abdul so you deliver it directly without any customization?

Answer (score 0):

First loop index is 0, so -1 index doesn't found into the $assignee array. You must add $loop->index > 0 control in if closure!

```php
@foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
<tr>
    @if(!$loop->first && $loop->index > 0 && $assignee->rfc_id == $assignee[$loop->index - 1]->rfc_id)
        <td>{{$assignee->rfc_id}} it matches!!</td>
    @else
        <td>Nope</td>
```